# when i submit its story in database but when if submit without filling data in input its show undefined index how to fix

Tags: php, mysql

```
<html>

<?php 

mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("demo");

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $post_name = $_POST['name']; 

    $post_gender = $_POST['gender'];

        if($post_name==''){

    echo "<div class='efe'>* All fields are mandatory...</div>" ;


        }
    else {



        $insert_query = "insert into demo
         (name,sex)
         values('$post_name','$post_gender')";

        if(mysql_query($insert_query)){

        echo "<div class='efe ewffs6re'>Post successfully...</div>";

        }
    }

}
?>  


<form method="post" class="iurtture4" align="left" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                <span>Name</span><input   type="text" name="name"  /><br>
                <span>Male</span><input type="radio" value="male"name="gender" /><br>

                <span>Female</span><input  type="radio" name="gender" value="female"placeholder="Enter"autocomplete="off"/><br>
        <button name="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you add some explanations please ?

Comment: What's your problem actually? and also title has no sence. change it

Comment: I think he is trying to tell us that he recieves a ```notice: undefined index...``` when not all input fields have values

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to get values from an array ($_POST, $_GET....) is:

```
$post_name = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : ''; 
$post_gender = isset($_POST['gender']) ? $_POST['gender'] : '';
```

It can be used without modifying other things in your code.